# Error in Launching AVD on Windows 7 in Android SDK 23

Tags: android, intel, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools, haxm

I have Windows 7(Ultimate edition) installed in my Dell Inspiron laptop with an Intel i5 processor. I have recently installed the latest Android SDK(SDK 23, Android 6.0) and it got successfully installed as well. Now when I launch AVD, I get the following error message:

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

[image: Error in Launching AVD]

Now the problem is, I have already enabled Virtualization from the BIOS and same verified from Intel Processor Identification Utility.

[image: Virtualization is enabled]

I navigated to my android sdk ...\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and double clicked on intelhaxm-android.exe.

I get the following error:
[image: The computer meets the requirements but VT-x is not turned on]

How to remove this error? What is it that could be causing the error?

Comment: If you have an antivirus installed on your system...please disable it or uninstall it till the time you complete installing haxm....Then in BIOS enable the Virtualization and install the haxm..After completing the installation enable or reinstall the antivirus

Comment: Yes I have anti-virus installed on my system; infact a couple of them- Avast and Microsoft Security essentials. So, i'll try a to uninstall both of them. And in BIOS, Virtualization is already enabled.

Comment: I had same problem with antivirus avast and kaspersky installed on my machine.Only uninstalling avast would do....bcoz avast has a setting for virtualization..I read it somewhere..if you search deep then you might also be able to find it.

Comment: Ok that could be probably a great help. I'll update after unistalling Avast. For a minute before posting on StackOverflow, I guessed that anti-virus might be causing this issue. But then I didn't pursue the thought because I had Virtualization enabled in BIOS and Intel Processor Identification Utility showed that it is up.
Anyways, let's see. And do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @ShadowDroid: Uninstalling the Avast anti-virus did really solved my problem. So, after I uninstalled the anti-virus, I rebooted my system and then navigated back to the Android SDK in ~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager then ran intelhaxm-android.exe with administrator privileges and Bingo! This time it got installed. So, emulator is up and running on my system now. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had Exact same issue u need to go to bios setting by reboot and enable VT option. Once done install intel driver for HAXM, Manually google, download and install it.