# HAXM is not installing

Tags: android, adt, haxm

I have:

- enabled Intel Virtualization technology from bios settings
- unchecked Avast antivirus
- enabled hardware assisted acceleration option
- disabled hyper V of windows 7

but still I cant install Intel HAXM.  When I tried to install it shows the same error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try uninstalling Avast and then restarting, It solved the problem for me, here is that answer [Error in Launching AVD on Windows 7 in Android SDK 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643459/error-in-launching-avd-on-windows-7-in-android-sdk-23#)

Or you can try [Troubleshooting Intel® HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm)